# Fiction story involving an undercover galactic officer piloting a logging mecha

Tags: story-identification, books

About 10 years ago I found a book in a Dollar General and though it looked interesting. It opened with a man piloting a logging mecha, before heading back to the Bunkhouse. I think he was given orders to be transferred, and we find out within a few pages he's actually an undercover officer for the Galactic Authorities.

He was recalled to go investigate a new casino being built(?). It had a lot of mecha fights written into it. The cover art had a man standing in front of a mecha in the forest

Comment: https://www.goodreads.com/en/book/show/602933.Firefight_Y2K?

Comment: No that's not the one but it does look interesting.

Comment: Did they actually use the word "mecha" in the novel?

Answer (score 5):

This is *[Mechwarrior: Ghost War](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/7716971-ghost-war)*.

> For generations, the Republic of the Sphere has known a Golden Age of peace. Mighty BattleMechs, once kings of the battlefields, now aid the reconstruction of war-torn worlds. But when terrorists destroy the interstellar communications net, each planet is thrust into isolation. Suddenly old hatreds resurface and a people who have never known war face the prospect of learning its meaning firsthand. **Sam Donelly is one of the best LumberMech jockeys on the planet, wielding his 'Mech's fifteen-foot chainsaw with the grace and precision of a surgeon. Caught in a skirmish with revolutionaries, he soon finds himself a rebel recruit.** But Sam is no mere lumberjack, and if his true identity is discovered, the repercussions could be disastrous not only for Sam, but for the entire Republic..
>
> [image]

Comment: That's the one. I swear it had a Lumber mech in the forest with a man standing in front of it but that's the story for sure. Thank you so much.

Comment: @Fallstalker92 - I'm trying to find an edition that has that cover.